# LINQ: overriding a column data with another table's data using FK relationship

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two tables as follows:

```
OriginalText(ID, LanguageId, Key, TextValue);
CustomText(ID, ClientID, FkOriginalTextId, TextValue);
```

The two tables are related through Foreign-key: FkOriginalTextId

Basically, OriginalText will have key/value pairs for different languages. If a particular client wants a certain value to be customized then it goes to the  CustomText table. An example would be OriginalText: Employee, CustomText: Staff-member for the key: *Employee*.

I want to write a Lambda/Linq to get all the text of a given language from the OriginalText table, but the TextValue should be overriden if there's a custom replacement for that key in the CustomText table. I can do this using multiple SQL statements by getting the OriginalText values to a temp table and later on updating them with CustomText value, but is there's a better way to do that? Perhaps using a CTE?

P.S. I want to do this using LINQ or Lambda expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As two tables have relations so, you can easily check if each `OriginalText` item has a `CustomText` or not. and get value from `CustomText` if exists:

```
OriginalText.Select(ot=> new OriginalText {
   TextValue = ot.CustomText.Any()? ot.CustomText.FirstOrDefault().TextValue:ot.TextValue,
   ID = ot.ID,
   LanguageId = ot.LanguageId,
   Key = ot.Key
});
```

Comment: Actually this didn't work. Whenever I had at least a single value in the CustomText table, text values for other rows came null.